# What’s the function of introns

Tags: introns

As far as i know, introns do not encode protein products, but living creatures still have them. So what’s their function ?

P/s: Sorry for my grammar

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. As you will see, this question has been asked before. You can find out whether your question has already been covered by searching for a term of interest like "intron". If you are on a desktop or laptop you will any case see a list of related questions in the right-hand sidebar. Also see [How to ask good questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help.

Answer (score -2):

Eukaryotic  organisms possess introns for few purposes. One of them which i know is protein isoform formation, where different combinations of exons can give rise to different forms of the same protein  which wouldn't have been  possible otherwise , if  we only had exons. Also introns code for SiRNAs  and few other RNAs.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Your answers will be much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). In addition, please don't answer questions that have been marked as duplicates — if you have **new** material to contribute please post that as an answer to the older question. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively. Thanks! 